# Codeigniter Update using Join

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

I try to update my table using join in Codeigniter but I get error

> Unknown column 'filter.ID_AREA' in 'where clause

```
$this->db->join('filter', 'filter.ID_AREA = area.ID_AREA', 'left');
$this->db->set('ID_VERIFIKASI', '3');
$this->db->where('pelayanan.ID_AREA', $ID_AREA);
$this->db->where('filter.ID_AREA', $ID_AREA);
$this->db->where('filter.ID_RAYON', $ID_RAYON);
$this->db->where('pelayanan.ID_RAYON = filter.F1_RAYON');
$this->db->where('SUBSTR(TGLRUBAH, 3, 6) = filter.F1_BULANTAHUN');
$this->db->where('ID_VERIFIKASI', '2');
$this->db->where('ID_KENDALA is not null');
$this->db->update('pelayanan');
if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
```

How can I update table using join in Codeigniter?

Comment: show your database tables structure

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you avoid UPDATE JOIN using the Query Builder. Use an SQL string and query it instead.

From what I see in your snippet you may try to convert it to something like this :

```
public function updateMyDB() {
    $sql = 
    "UPDATE pelayanan P " .
    "LEFT JOIN filter F ON F.ID_AREA = area.ID_AREA " .
    "SET ID_VERIFIKASI = 3 "
    "WHERE P.ID_AREA = " . $ID_AREA .
    "AND F.ID_AREA = " . $ID_AREA .
    "AND F.ID_RAYON = " . $ID_RAYON .
    "AND P.ID_RAYON = F.F1_RAYON " .
    "AND SUBSTR(TGLRUBAH, 3, 6) = F.F1_BULANTAHUN " .
    "AND ID_VERIFIKASI = 2 " .
    "AND ID_KENDALA IS NOT NULL";

    $this->db->query($sql);

    return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0);
}
```

This is a not a perfect query, there is no reference to table "area" and to ID_VERIFIKASI and ID_KENDALA. I didn't test the query but I'm pretty sure it will fail in the JOIN, but you got the idea. Up to you to create the correct sql for your needs :)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
function edit_save($data, $post_id, $user_id)
{
    $this->db->set($data)
    $this->db->where('table1.user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('table1.post_id', $post_id);
    $this->db->where('table1.data_id_fk = table2.data_id');
    $this->db->update('table1, table2');
}
```